# Localization of $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ w.r.t. the set of all nonzero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R=\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and $S$ the set of all nonzero divisors of $R$. Then what is the localization $S^{-1}R$?

Help me plz.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: show that in $R$, the non zero-divisors are precisely the units. What do you get if you localize a ring at the set of its units? (Use the universal property of localization.)

Comment: More generally, in any commutative Artinian ring, there are only zero divisors and units. Thus they are all already equal to their respective classical rings of quotients.

Answer (score 1):

$$S^{-1}R=\left\{\;\frac ab\;\;;\;\;a\in R\;,\;\;b\in S\;\right\}$$

Remember that, by definition, we have

$$\text{For}\;\;\frac ab\,,\,\frac cd\in S^{-1}R\;,\;\;\frac ab=\frac cd\iff\exists\,s\in S\;s.t.\; (ad-bc)s=0\stackrel{\text{why?}}\iff ad-bc=0\;$$

Now work some examples with small $\;n\;$ to get a feeling of what you get each time...